# Future Dates SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a constraint that does not allow dates in future years. I have this:

```
ALTER TABLE PACIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT ck_FechaNacimiento
CHECK (FechaNacimiento<=current_date);
```

But i'm getting `error 02436`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a non-deterministic constraint.  So you cannot create a constraint that references a function like `current_date` or `sysdate` that returns a different value every time you call it.

If you want to enforce this sort of thing, you'd need to create a trigger on the table that throws an error if the business rule is violated, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_paciente
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON paciente
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.FechaNacimiento > current_date )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'FechaNacimiento<=current_date must be in the past' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried again with this and didn't show error, thanks by the way:

ALTER TABLE EXAMENPACIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT ExamenPaciente_FechaExamen_c1 
CHECK (FechaExamen<='30-SEP-2013');

Answer (score -3):

```
ALTER TABLE PACIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT ck_FechaNacimiento CHECK (FechaNacimiento<=SYSDATE);
```

Comment: You'd get the same error using the `SYSDATE` function that you'd get with `CURRENT_DATE`.  Both are non-deterministic and non-deterministic functions are not allowed in constraints.